# Can .Net 4.7 project, reference .Net Core 2.0 Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Looking forward to leverage .Net Core (EF Core) while stick together with old web API.

> Can .Net 4.7 project, reference .Net Core 2.0 Class Library? Have been
>   waiting for this feature, since 1.0. Is it supported?

Comment: .net Core can't be referenced, you can reference .net Standard libraries.

Comment: Note that EF Core is a .NET Standard 2.0 library and can be used on both .NET Core and .NET Standard. There also is ASP.NET Core 2.0 on .NET Framework (since ASP.NET Core is also .NET Standard 2.0)

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I've been Googling for 15 minutes and still think the answer is muddy- let's not discourage people from asking questions.

Comment: Sorry @SamRueby not muddy at all. As I said it took me about a minute to find the answer to that question. "Give a man a fish..." Let's encourage people to feed themselves ;)